# Creating a storage space or server from multiple laptop HDDs

Tags: hard-drive

I've 4 - 5 unused laptop HDDs laying around, totaling a couple of Terabytes. That's space I could be making use of! (instead of worrying about my `/home` folder taking up all my space).

I have a very handy screwless external which makes switching these easy, but I'd like to do something a little more advanced. The only problem is: hardware is my weak spot.

Is there something I can do to make good use of these? What would it take to use them in a little personal server, or just a big box with a single USB cable (maybe some kind of array where they can all be plugged in?)

Comment: You need a usb jbod enclosure....https://startpage.com/do/search?query=usb+jbod+enclosure&cat=web&pl=chrome&language=english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use them all at once with one single USB, you can search for a hard drive enclosure with multiple bays. here is an example of it http://goo.gl/YNpwva , this just an example that will give you a better look on which enclosure you need. There are many kinds on the market, and they're all have some unique features.

The things you will need to focus on while searching are :

**What are the hard drives physical size that you have:**

Some brands, gives you the option of using 3.5" and 2.5" drives, others are designed only on one size either a 3.5" or 2.5".

**What kind of connection you need:**

The kind of connection that you are going to use to hook it up in the computer is important. You may find USB 3.0, but you prefer Thunderbolt connector since your computer support it. So, the better the connector the faster data transfer between computer and hard drives.

**How many bays you need:**

There are products supports up to 8 bays and more, so if you have around 5 drives, it will be a waste of money if you bought 8 bays because there will be 3 unused bays. You can search for 5 bays to hook all 5 drives, or you can get 6 bays, and hook up the 5 drives leaving one bay for a future drive.

**How much capacity in total you're going to use:**

This is also important since enclosures have a maximum capacity that can read. So, the bigger capacity that enclosure support, the higher drive capacity can be used.

**Some Features that most have**

These features in my opinion are important to be built-in the enclosure.

- The enclosure should have a cooling system to maintain the drives temperate.
- It should have SATA 3 connectors for the hard drives.
- It should support multiple hard disk group like RAID & JBOD.
- Should also have a screen indicator to watch your drives status.

Comment: Excellent! 

Is this something that, if I wanted, I could eventually expand into a server?

Comment: @AmagicalFishy you could expand it into a server and there are many ways to do that, but you need to prepare it for that if you know how to work with servers. However, you can buy NAS (Network Attached Storage) if you're going to build a server or a cloud storage.